# What are the alternatives to angular js?

Tags: angularjs

New to front end development here. Discovered Yeoman, seems like a great tool. I worked through a tutorial and then completed a small project using Angular JS with a Node JS backend. To assist in looking at things from my perspective: at this point I don't know enough web development to abstract my approach, I just know the set of tools I can use to get something working. I know if I want to make a new web site I can generate a project using Yeoman, fiddle with the HTML/CSS, and make the content dynamic with Angular. It actually works pretty well.

However, I am curious as to what the other approaches to web development are. What are the alternatives to Angular JS? Is Angular.js the standard/common approach?

Answer (score 5):

There are tons of Javascript frameworks out there. AngularJS is quite popular, but by no means the standard or common practice. Other popular frameworks you may want to look into are [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) for full stack apps, [ReactJS](https://facebook.github.io/react/), [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/), [Ember](http://emberjs.com/), and many many more for front-end Javascript frameworks. Also, taking a step back, there are tons of other approaches to web development other than just considering what's on the front end (HTML, CSS and JS). For example, you can build whole websites without even touching javascript using Ruby on Rails. Other big frameworks are Python's Django, PHP with Drupal, Wordpress, Joomla, etc., and .NET / C# just to mention a few. Hope that gets your research started.

Comment: I think one of the biggest difficulties for a beginner like me are that there are way too many options for how to do things. For that reason it's hard for me to ask a "good" stackOverflow question on this topic, because I'm at most only able to ask "which direction is good to go in" or "what other options are there" which are by nature softer, more subjective questions. I appreciate the answer, will check that stuff out.